# Generating 2 files based on two columns in a third file

Tags: perl, unix, awk, grep

I am trying to prepare two input files based on information in a third file. File 1 is for sample1 and File 2 is for sample2. Both these files have lines with tab delimited columns. The first column contains unique identifier and the second column contains information.

File 1

```
>ENT01 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>ENT02 xyxyxyxyxyxy
>ENT03 ththththththt
```

..so on. Similarly, File 2 contains

```
>ENG012 ggggggggggggg
>ENG098 ksksksksksks
>ENG234 wewewewewew
```

I have a File 3 that contains two columns each corresponding to the identifier from File 1 and File 2

```
>ENT01 >ENG78
>ENT02 >ENG098
>ENT02 >ENG012
>ENT02 >ENG234
>ENT03 >ENG012
```

and so on. I want to prepare input files for File 1 and File 2 by following the order in file 3. If an entry is repeated in file 3 (ex ENT02) I want to repeat the information for that entry. The expected output is
For File 1:

```
>ENT01 xxxxxxxxxx
>ENT02 xyxyxyxyxyxy
>ENT02 xyxyxyxyxyx
>ENT02 xyxyxyxyxyx
>ENT03 ththththththth
```

And for file 2

```
>ENG78 some info
>ENG098 ksksksksks
>ENG012 gggggggg
>ENG234 wewewewewew
>ENG012 gggggggg
```

All the the entries in file 1 and file 2 are unique but not in file 3. Also, there are some entries in file3 in either column that is not present in either file 1 or file 2. The current logic I am using is that finding an intersection  of identifiers from column 1 in both files1&2 with respective columns in file 3, storing this as a list and using this list to compare with File1 and File 2 separately to generate output for File 1 & 2. I am working with the following lines

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next};{print a[$1]}' file1 intersectlist`

`grep -v -x -f idsnotfoundinfile1 file3`

I am not able to get the right output as I think at some point it is getting sorted and only uniq values are printed out. Can someone please help me clear work this out.

Comment: 1) Is `>ENT02 xyxyxyxyxyxy` in the "_expected output_" for File1 a typo? The last `y` shouldn't be there? 2) So what do you want to do when an entry in File3 does not exist in File 1/2?

Comment: It sounds like the two columns in `File 3` are independent, and could actually be in two different files. The file simply specifies an ordering of the records from `File 1` and `File 2`. Is that right?

Comment: Do you really want `some info` substituted where there is no information for an ID in the main files. For instance, there is no entry for `>ENG78`, but your required output shows `>ENG78 some info`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read and remember the first 2 files into some data structure, and then for the third file, output to 2 new files:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
      FNR == 1 {file_num++}
      file_num == 1 || file_num == 2 {data[file_num,$1] = $2; next}
      function value(str) {
          return str ? str : "some info"
      }
      {
          for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {
              print $i, value(data[i,$i]) > ARGV[i] ".new"
          }
      }
  ' file1 file2 file3


$ cat file1.new
>ENT01  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>ENT02  xyxyxyxyxyxy
>ENT02  xyxyxyxyxyxy
>ENT02  xyxyxyxyxyxy
>ENT03  ththththththt

$ cat file2.new
>ENG78  some info
>ENG098 ksksksksksks
>ENG012 ggggggggggggg
>ENG234 wewewewewew
>ENG012 ggggggggggggg
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, just running the above code with the example files, the output I get is different from your output file1.new looks like `>ENT01 >ENG78 some info
>ENT02 >ENG098 some info
>ENT02 >ENG012 some info
>ENT02 >ENG234 some info
>ENT03 >ENG012 some info` sorry I am not able to format the comment.  I have three columns in file1.new where the first two columns are from file3 and third column has 'some info'

Comment: Yes. They are tab separated. I am sorry for the delay in responding.

Comment: Well, that's what `-F'\t'` and `-v OFS='\t'` are for. Did you use them?

Answer (score 1):

The files 1 and 2 first need be read so that you can find their lines with identifiers from file 3. Since the identifiers in these files are unique you can build a hash for each file, with identifiers as keys.

Then process file 3 line by line, where for each identifier on the line retrieve its value from the hash for the appropriate file and write the corresponding lines to new files 1 and 2.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Path::Tiny;

my ($file1, $file2, $file3) = qw(File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt);

my ($fileout1, $fileout2) = map { $_ . 'new' } ($file1, $file2);

my %file1 = map { split } path($file1)->lines;
my %file2 = map { split } path($file2)->lines;

my ($ofh1, $ofh2) = map { path($_)->openw } ($fileout1, $fileout2);

open my $fh, '<', $file3 or die "Can't open $file3: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    my ($f1, $f2) = split;

    say $ofh1 "$f1\t", $file1{$f1} // 'some info';   #/ see text
    say $ofh2 "$f2\t", $file2{$f2} // 'some info';
}
close $_ for $ofh1, $ofh2, $fh;
```

This produces the correct output based on fragments of input files that are provided.

I use [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm) here for its conciseness. Its `lines` method returns all lines, and in [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)'s block each is [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) by default space. The list of such pairs returned by `map` is assigned to a hash, whereby each pair of successive strings forms a key-value pair.

Multiple files can be opened in one statement, and `Path::Tiny` again makes it clean with `openw`.  Its methods throw the exception (`die`) on errors, so we get error checking as well.

If an identifier in File 3 is not found in File 1/2 I bluntly use `'some info'` as stated in the question,<sup>†</sup> but I expect that there is a more rounded solution for such a case.  Then the laconic `//` should be changed to accommodate extra processing (or call a sub in place of `'some info'` string).

It is assumed that files 1 and 2 always have two entries on a line.

Some shortcuts are taken, like reading each file into a hash in one line. Please expand the code as appropriate, with whatever checks may be needed.

---

<sup>†</sup> In such a case `$file1{$f1}` is `undef` so `//` (defined-or) operator returns its right-hand-side argument. A "proper" way is to test `if (exist $file1{$f1})` but `//` works as well.

Comment: @user210432  Edited answer to add `'some info'` for the missing identifiers.  Please clarify a few points, by responding to comments below the question.

Comment: @user210432 Edited the answer to make it more concise and demonstrate a few useful things